What is the meaning of “that is a deeply packed question”
If someone says to you that is a deeply packed question what do they mean? Does it have a negative connotation?

Did you encounter this usage somewhere, or are you just thinking of it? It's not a common phrase, especially compared to some others. It would help if we could use context to guess at a meaning, because the speaker could be trying (inexpertly) to convey "deep" (profound), or "multi-layered," or "loaded/fraught" (i.e. "carrying a lot of baggage"), or even something else like "obscure" or "inaccessible." Voting to close as unclear; please edit.

How did this get closed when it has an accepted answer?

It's an allusion to a meaning of unpack: "to analyze the nature of by examining in detail" (Merriam-Webster)
If something is packed it requires to be unpacked, so a question that is "deeply packed" needs a lot of unpacking, i.e. it's difficult and needs a lot of detailed examination to solve.
You can find a lot of examples of this use of unpack online, e.g. from James Cook University in Australia:

Here's an example of how to unpack an essay question.
The first step is to read the question carefully to familiarise yourself with the general subject you will
write about.
Next, we find topic words that identify the subject of the essay.
...
Then, we find task words that tell us what to do.

There are fewer uses of "packed" with questions, but it's a natural extension of meaning. "Unpacking" and "packing" typically don't just refer to something that's difficult, but more specifically something where you need to think about what the question is, define your terms, work out what is required, etc.
It should be obvious that it's not necessarily negative, unless you consider it negative to say a question needs effort to solve.
